# Need help by creating a dialog with 2 NumberPickers

Tags: android, numberpicker

I'm trying to create a dialog with 2 NumberPickers. I would like them to be default Holo theme styled. I cant find any good examples. So far i got:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
        getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View npView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_picker_dialog, null);
        NumberPicker minPicker = (NumberPicker) npView.findViewById(R.id.min_picker);
        minPicker.setMaxValue(100);
        minPicker.setMinValue(0);
        NumberPicker maxPicker = (NumberPicker) npView.findViewById(R.id.max_picker);
        maxPicker.setMaxValue(100);
        maxPicker.setMinValue(0);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Text Size:");
        builder.setView(npView);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Okay",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            });
       builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    }
                });
       dialog = builder.create();
       dialog.show();
```

number_picker_dialog xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:holo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" 
 android:gravity="center">

<NumberPicker 
    android:id="@+id/min_picker"
    android:width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:/>

<NumberPicker 
    android:id="@+id/max_picker"
    android:width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But the colorpicker text are white (Like the background), and i cant set the textColor of the NumberPicker.

How can i set the textColor or does anyone knows a good NumberPicker example?

Comment: Apply a style to the NumberPicker that has a textViewStyle set with the text color you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem why my NumberPicker wasn't Holo.Light styled:

instead of calling:

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View npView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_picker_dialog, null);
```

i solved it by calling:

```
 View npView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.number_picker_dialog, null);
```

Comment: Not sure why this change worked for you. The `before` and `after` statements are equivalent. You can test it - `getLayoutInflater() == (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)` ==> `true`.

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to create a Custom Dialog class as show below.

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {
     public CustomDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.customDialog); //use your style id from styles.xml
     }

     public void setNumberDialog() {
          setContentView(R.layout.number_picker_dialog);
          //add required listeners
          show();
     }
}
```

Invoke the dialog from calling acitivty.

```
 new CustomDialog(context).setNumberDialog();
```

And the style parameters are defined in styles.xml

```
<style name="customDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thnx for your help, but i found the real problem

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<NumberPicker
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance">
</NumberPicker>
```