# NumberPicker textColour

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have a `ListView` containing a `TextView` and a `NumberPicker` for each row.
Whenever I start up the activity, the numbers of the `NumberPicker` are white (the same color as the background).

I tried applying  a style as suggested [here](http://pastebin.com/uR0bUikP), [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882707/need-help-by-creating-a-dialog-with-2-numberpickers) ; to no avail.

Any other suggestions?

-

**NumberPicker.xml**

```
<NumberPicker 
    android:id="@+id/npMaterialAmount"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    style="@style/npColour"/>
```

-

**Tried style 1:**

```
<style name = "npColour" >
    <item name = "android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

-

**Tried style 2:**

```
<style name = "npColour" parent ="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>
```

-

**... and the list goes on...**

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031624/how-to-change-number-picker-style-in-android)

Comment: Well, you are setting the color of the `NumberPicker` to white -> `<item name = "android:textColor">#000000</item>`, why do you wonder why it's white ?

Comment: The hex code for black color is #000000

Comment: @g00dy for your info > http://www.color-hex.com/color/000000

Comment: Sorry - my bad, to set the style of the `numberPicker` use something like that - <style name="npColour" parent="@style/Holo.NumberPicker">
  <item name="selectionDivider">#ff5500</item>
</style>` see if this does the trick.

Comment: You can even customize this further - `<item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/Theme.Holo.NumberPicker</item>`

Comment: No resource found that matches `'@style/Theme.Holo.NumberPicker'`

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old. I founded the answer here: [Change the text color of NumberPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962075/change-the-text-color-of-numberpicker)

Copy:

> This code should solve your problem. The problem you are experiencing is because during the construction of NumberPicker it captures the EditText textColor and assigns to to a paint so it can draw the numbers above and below the edit text with the same color.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public static boolean setNumberPickerTextColor(NumberPicker numberPicker, int color)
{
    final int count = numberPicker.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        View child = numberPicker.getChildAt(i);
        if(child instanceof EditText){
            try{
                Field selectorWheelPaintField = numberPicker.getClass()
                    .getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(true);
                ((Paint)selectorWheelPaintField.get(numberPicker)).setColor(color);
                ((EditText)child).setTextColor(color);
                numberPicker.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
            catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
                Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
            }
            catch(IllegalAccessException e){
                Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Are you using a [Formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setFormatter%28android.widget.NumberPicker.Formatter%29)? I had to use [setDisplayedValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setDisplayedValues%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) to fix the problem.
I assume you have already solved this problem, but I'm posting this anyway, I for one was desperate looking for an answer, solved it by accident.

```
    NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(5);     
    String[] periodicityValues = {"Semanal", "Mensal", "Bimestral", "Trimestral", "Semestral", "Anual"};
    numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(periodicityValues);
```

Comment: how does this change the text color ?

Comment: Exactly, how it will change the text color