# Change the text color of NumberPicker

Tags: android, textcolor, numberpicker

I've looked at most all of the threads on this and none provided an answer that works. Styling the NumberPicker does not work (as per this thread: [NumberPicker textColour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120840/numberpicker-textcolour))

Setting the style attribute on the numberPicker to a style that has a color item does not have any effect either. Nor does setting the textColor attribute on the numberPicker XML do anything.

Closest I've got to this is using the numberPicker to cast its getChildAt() to an EditText and then do setColor() on that EditText, but that only changes the color of the child once upon initialization and then every time it is selected from thereon; not what I am looking for either.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The solution I tried and worked for me is:

In styles.xml add:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Picker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Then use it like this inside your layout:

```
  <NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/dialogPicker"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
```

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer overall. +1

Comment: Definately the simplest solution!

This is also easy to combine with my custom numberpicker, for which used the theme @android:style/Theme.Dialog to show + and - buttons instead of the slider effect.

Now I simply defined the parent as my previous theme (instead of Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar), and it magically works combined.

Comment: This is the best answer. I wish I could up-vote more then +1.

Comment: @z3n105 do you know the property for changing the selection color?

Comment: This answer changes color of all fields of number picker, I mean color of unselected fields will change, too. But what if I want to change just selected field?!

Comment: Maybe a bit delayed but if anyone can't find the styles.xml:
The styles got migrated into `values\themes.xml` (with optional themes for day and night).

Answer (score 74):

This code should solve your problem. The problem you are experiencing is because during the construction of NumberPicker it captures the EditText textColor and assigns to to a paint so it can draw the numbers above and below the edit text with the same color.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public static void setNumberPickerTextColor(NumberPicker numberPicker, int color)
{

    try{
        Field selectorWheelPaintField = numberPicker.getClass()
            .getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
        selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(true);
        ((Paint)selectorWheelPaintField.get(numberPicker)).setColor(color);
    }
    catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
        Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
    }
    catch(IllegalAccessException e){
        Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
    }

    final int count = numberPicker.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        View child = numberPicker.getChildAt(i);
        if(child instanceof EditText)
            ((EditText)child).setTextColor(color);
    }
    numberPicker.invalidate();  
}
```

Comment: This worked! even with net.simonvt.numberpicker ! It made me crazy that no matter what style I specified, I kept ending up with black text! (black text on black background = useless)

Comment: Worked for me. You saved me from jumping off my apartment.

Comment: All you need to do is override `textColorPrimary` in your theme. Calling on Reflection API is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Agreed. However it must be said that this also changes the text color in your entire app and not just the date time picker which may not suite. The question is specific to NumberPicker.

Comment: @Vikram, to be honest all it **should** have required is  `android:textColor="@android:color/white"`

Comment: @Simon For some reason I missed your reply! I guess you forgot to add `(at)Vikram` to your comment. You said: `..this also changes the text color in your entire app..`. Well, we can use `ContextThemeWrapper` to create the `LayoutInflater` that inflates the `date/time/numberpicker`. This way, our overridden `textColorPrimary` affects only the picker, leaving everything else intact. BUT, I do realize that your solution is alright too. I read this somewhere: *Reflection is the ability to make modifications at runtime by making use of introspection*. So, your usage of reflection is well justified.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Eccentricities of the little green robot.

Comment: I don't like to downvote, and this answer shows good effort, and works, but it is so much worse than @Vikram's answer below that I am downvoting, because I think the community will be better served by Vikram's answer.

Comment: Awesome! great solution!

Comment: If there is a user interaction, the color changes to the default one. @Simon

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere tried to implement the above code but it is not working for me can you please tell me Where I did the mistake https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258539/how-to-change-the-timepicker-color

Comment: are you getting a "NoSuchFieldException"? Since this code snippet is a while old, I presume that Google has changed the layout and changed the name of the field. It might be better to give Vikram's answer a go, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314989/550471

Comment: I don't believe this is the best answer. I believe the best answer now is by z3n105

Comment: I tried this but not successful.  If you log the getChildCount value it always returns 1.  If you change the colour you find out that the one child is the selected value and it shows this in the layout inspector as well.  Is it the normal NumberPicker that was being used?  I also noticed that when the value changed the colour was also lost but returns if you tap on the selected value.

Comment: check z3n105 answer, this is a better solution as android changes this method and you can not access to this method via reflection now

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the answer. It changes color of selected field first time number picker is shown. But if I click on number picker or scroll it, colors will return to default color. What is the problem?!

Answer (score 40):

Not sure why you would need to dive into Java Reflection API for this. Its a simple styling matter. The attribute that you need to override is: `textColorPrimary`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    ....
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

If you're using the `TimePicker` inside a `Dialog`, override `android:textColorPrimary` in the dialog's theme.

That's about it.

**Additional info:**

Here's an insightful comment by [Yoann Hercouet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206688/yoann-hercouet):

> This solution does not change only the color on the NumberPicker, it
>   is a global change that will impact A LOT of components

This is correct, but it overlooks the possibilities I am hinting at. Moreover, `global` implies app-wide impact. That can be limited to activity-scope by applying this theme only to activities containing the `NumberPicker`. But, I agree, this may still be too *corrosive*.

The idea here is to somehow inject `textColorPrimary=INTENDED_COLOR` into the theme that will be seen by `NumberPicker`. There are multiple ways to achieve this. Here's one way:

Define a bare-bone style in `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="NumberPickerTextColorStyle">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/intended_color</item>
</style>
```

Now, create a custom `NumberPicker`:

```
public class ThemedNumberPicker extends NumberPicker {

    public ThemedNumberPicker(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ThemedNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        // wrap the current context in the style we defined before
        super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.NumberPickerTextColorStyle), attrs);
    }
}
```

Finally, use `ThemedNumberPicker` in your layout(s):

```
<package.name.ThemedNumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    ....
    ....
    .... />
```

We have successfully contained the impact that `textColorPrimary=INTENDED_COLOR` has on our app.

This is of course just one option. For example, if you were inflating a layout containing a `NumberPicker`, you could use:

```
// In this case, the layout contains <NumberPicker... />, not <ThemedNumberPicker... />
LayoutInflater.from(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.NumberPickerTextColorStyle))
    .inflate(R.layout.number_picker_layout, ...);
```

Comment: A much better approach.

Comment: @Milad If you can give/post some more details about your app setup, I can probably help you out.

Comment: doesn't work on me either. But using this method worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882707/need-help-by-creating-a-dialog-with-2-numberpickers

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Like I said to user Milad - if you can post your style setup, I can probably help you out. Moreover, the answer you linked to doesn't make sense (unfortunately). See my comment on that answer.

Comment: It had to do with using the right LayoutInflater. The one from SystemService would not work.

Comment: This solution does not change only the color on the NumberPicker, it is a global change that will impact A LOT of components.

Comment: @YoannHercouet Thank you for pointing this out. Made me realise that my answer may not be as clear as I had thought. Please check the `edit` I've made to it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a Xamarin Snippet from the answer above with TextSize and TextStyle Bold

```
public static bool SetNumberPickerTextColorAndSize(NumberPicker numberPicker, Color color, ComplexUnitType complexUnitType, float textSize, TypefaceStyle style)
    {
        int count = numberPicker.ChildCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            View child = numberPicker.GetChildAt(i);
            if (child.GetType() == typeof(EditText))
            {
                try
                {
                    Field selectorWheelPaintField = numberPicker.Class
                                                                .GetDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                    selectorWheelPaintField.Accessible = true;

                    EditText editText = (EditText) child;
                    editText.SetTextSize(complexUnitType, textSize);
                    editText.SetTypeface(editText.Typeface, style);
                    editText.SetTextColor(color);

                    Paint paint = (Paint) selectorWheelPaintField.Get(numberPicker);
                    paint.TextSize =  TypedValue.ApplyDimension(complexUnitType, textSize, numberPicker.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
                    paint.Color = color;
                    paint.SetTypeface(editText.Typeface);

                    numberPicker.Invalidate();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
                {
                    Log.Warn("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
                }
                catch (IllegalAccessException e)
                {
                    Log.Warn("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
                {
                    Log.Warn("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: ComplexUnitType class not found

Comment: Where do you call this? From a custom renderer?

Comment: I can't find `addView` inside the code of `NumberPicker`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Been looking for this for a while. If anyone is using Xamarin.Android, you put this snippet inside your MainActivity or Fragment. You get your numberpicker with FindViewById, and pass it to the method.

Answer (score 8):

For me setting `android:textColorPrimary` in my theme did nothing, looking at the source code for the `NumberPicker` it decides the text color from the `EditText` input thus one need to set the `android:editTextColor` instead.

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/dark_gray</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I believe [Dinidiniz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33673759/199364) already pointed that out.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of changing every text color to the color you want, better just changing all editText color. NumberPicker actually has a child EditText that display the numbers.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Change edit color here. -->
        <item name="android:editTextColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

This worked for me. And although I have white text in the buttons, they havent changed.

Comment: Hi, I want to just change selected edittext color, does your code do that?

Answer (score 4):

Based on reflection reject on Android SDK >= 29 better to modify Simon's answer:

```
public void setNumberPickerTextColor(NumberPicker numberPicker, int color){

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

        final int count = numberPicker.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = numberPicker.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof EditText) {
                try {
                    ((EditText) child).setTextColor(color);
                    numberPicker.invalidate();

                    Field selectorWheelPaintField = numberPicker.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                    boolean accessible = selectorWheelPaintField.isAccessible();
                    selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(true);
                    ((Paint) selectorWheelPaintField.get(numberPicker)).setColor(color);
                    selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(accessible);
                    numberPicker.invalidate();

                    Field selectionDividerField = numberPicker.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectionDivider");
                    accessible = selectionDividerField.isAccessible();
                    selectionDividerField.setAccessible(true);
                    selectionDividerField.set(numberPicker, null);
                    selectionDividerField.setAccessible(accessible);
                    numberPicker.invalidate();
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    Logger.exc(exception);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {

        numberPicker.setTextColor(color);
    }
}
```

In SDK >= 29 NumberPicker have .setTextColor() method.

Comment: warning
Reflective access to mSelectionDivider, which is not part of the public SDK and therefore likely to change in future Android releases

Answer (score 2):

I took the solution of [@Andreas Merz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26657169/2313889) and updated his code. The way things were assigned and the functions signatures/calls he used were not found. I am using `min API 19`. Here is the code that worked for me.

```
/**
 * Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/26657169/2313889
 * @param picker
 * @param color
 * @param unit
 * @param textSize
 * @param typeface
 * @return
 */
private void formatNumberPickerText(NumberPicker picker, int color,
                                    int unit, float textSize,
                                    Typeface typeface) {
    int count = picker.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = picker.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof EditText) {
            try {
                Class clazz = picker.getClass();
                Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                field.setAccessible(true);

                EditText editText = (EditText) child;
                editText.setTextSize(unit, textSize);
                editText.setTypeface(typeface);
                editText.setTextColor(color);

                Paint paint = (Paint) field.get(picker);
                paint.setTextSize(TypedValue.applyDimension(
                        unit, textSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
                ));
                paint.setColor(color);
                paint.setTypeface(typeface);

                picker.invalidate();
                return;

            } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: Andreas code was for *Xamarin* Android. This answer is for "normal" Android code (Java), as was the original question. In comparison to the accepted answer, it adds setting of typeface and font size.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is overly complicated. A much simpler approach that worked for me was to override the: `textColorPrimary` attribute of the theme I was using.

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
</style>
```

It did the job quite well!

Answer (score 1):

For `Kotlin` users, use this extension function ( Based on `@Tapa Save` answer ).

```kotlin
fun NumberPicker.changeTextColor(color: Int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val count: Int = childCount
        for (i in 0 until count) {
            val child: View = getChildAt(i)
            if (child is EditText) {
                try {
                    child.setTextColor(color)
                    invalidate()
                    val selectorWheelPaintField: Field = this.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint")
                    var accessible: Boolean = selectorWheelPaintField.isAccessible
                    selectorWheelPaintField.isAccessible = true
                    (selectorWheelPaintField.get(this) as Paint).color = color
                    selectorWheelPaintField.isAccessible = accessible
                    invalidate()
                    val selectionDividerField: Field = this.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mSelectionDivider")
                    accessible = selectionDividerField.isAccessible()
                    selectionDividerField.isAccessible = true
                    selectionDividerField.set(this, null)
                    selectionDividerField.isAccessible = accessible
                    invalidate()
                } catch (ignore: Exception) { }
            }
        }
    } else {
        textColor = color
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's easy with my NumberPicker [library](https://github.com/tomeeeS/ScrollPickerDemo/blob/master/README.md).

```
<com.github.tomeees.scrollpicker.ScrollPicker
    ...
    app:textColor="..."
    />
```