# Change the text color of single item of NumberPicker

Tags: android, textcolor, numberpicker

The answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962075/change-the-text-color-of-numberpicker) works very good. However i would like to change the color of only a single item.
I have been messing around, and can't get it to work after one touches the NumberPicker. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to do this

```
if(i==yourItem){
        try{
            Field selectorWheelPaintField = numberPicker.getClass()
                .getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
            selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(true);
            ((Paint)selectorWheelPaintField.get(numberPicker)).setColor(color);
            ((EditText)child).setTextColor(color);
            numberPicker.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
            Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException e){
            Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
        }
}
```

I hope that this help you.