# Material Date Picker text color

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to change the text color of my DatePicker

```
 <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/start_date_text"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            style="@style/MyDatePicker" />
```

This code just gives 3 pickers, month, day and year. How can I change this text color?

```
 <style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
</style>
```

where Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker has been all the DatePicker options under Widget

Comment: For a DatePickerDialog check my answer on **Change DatePicker header text color** http://stackoverflow.com/a/42460022/5188159

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As with most components, the `DatePicker`'s text color is effected by `textColorPrimary`:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/Black</item>
```

Comment: This doesn't change the color of the text.

Comment: It only works if it is in your main app theme. It's somewhat difficult to change the font color directly because it is buried under several layout and ultimately the `EditText` itself will be styled as `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` which essentially only will refer to the `textColorPrimary` in your main theme. This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962075/change-the-text-color-of-numberpicker. If you want to change it for a `DatePicker`, it would require another outer loop to go though the `DatePicker`'s children to find the `NumberPicker`s.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very involved process to change something so simple. My app can get by with just using a consistent color throughout though.

Comment: adding this to the base app theme did the trick, Thanks!
one note : this does only change numbers color, but not days letters in the top
to change days letters as well you should override android:textColorSecondary.
Happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

An updated version would be to use `editTextColor` instead of using `textColorPrimary` and time pickers as suggested by tachyonflux date.

try:

```
<style name="NumberPickerStyle" >
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what your style have but you can do it this way:

```
<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker">

  <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>

</style>
```

Comment: I have tried that already and it doesn't work. I tried all the DatePickers under widget and no changes were seen with textColor

Comment: @JordanCarlyon Could you show us MyDatePicker style in your post ?

Comment: It's the name as yours but I did add it.