# How to change date color in default Date dialog?

Tags: android, datetimepicker, timepicker, android-timepicker

I know this post is duplicate but previously I didn't get any positive response that why re-posting it.

Currently the date picker is look like this.

I want to change the color date color ( currently set to black.)

Datepicker theme.

```
<style name="myDatePickertheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
            <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/white</item>
            <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
```

@color/white

Solution Tried:

@color/white

in the custom theme.

Min api=17

App theme

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/primary_background</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/myDialog</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/myDatePickertheme</item>

    </style>
```

Beside the above setting, I also use all the customisation provided by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738089/change-datepicker-dialog-color-for-android-5-0)

Comment: Have you try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738089/change-datepicker-dialog-color-for-android-5-0

Comment: Yes.. I have tried But didn't help @MavyaSoni

Comment: In which version you have tested?

Comment: Android 5.1.1 @MavyaSoni

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321039/material-date-picker-text-color

Comment: tried but no help @KrupaKakkad