# Nativescript Datepicker change text color

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to change the datepicker color to white in Android. I've tried with colorPrimary in styles.xml with no luck:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/SpinnerDatePicker</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>
```

Also, is there a way to use one color in a component and another in a second or am I bound to use one color for the whole app?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the color of the DatePicker dynamically... at least it is not a trivial job. The thing is that even in native Android changing the color via code-behind can be achieved only with the Reflection API (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26126181/4936697) for details).

To change the text color of the DatePicker there is one important thing to notice - you should apply `android:textColorPrimary` **directly** in the main **app theme** (see the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31323963/4936697) for details)

For example:
***values-v21/style.xml***

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/ns_green</item> <!-- HERE -->
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/SpinnerDatePicker</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/SpinnerTimePicker</item>
</style>
```

In the example above `ns_green` is defined in `colors.xml`

```
<color name="ns_green">#1eb234</color>
```

Comment: Ok, but even if I can't change it dynamically (that was my second question). Why is not at least presented in the color I'm setting for the whole app? Thanks!

Comment: I've extended my answer to demonstrate how to change the text color via the styles.xml file