# Nativescript-vue: how to change datepicker color?

Tags: nativescript-vue

In my setting page, a `Settings.vue` file I've my `DatePicker`

```
<template>
  <Page>
    <DatePicker/>
 </Page>
</template>
```

I need to change the default style.

> Note: actually I'm working specifically on Android, but please, answer keeping in mind I need the same colors on both Android and iOs; thanks,

I tried (in app.scss file

```
Datepicker {
  color: white;
}
```

Without success, as you can see my android emulator is using a near-black color.

[image]

Following [this guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/date-picker#styling), I changed `colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ns_primary">#577eac</color>
    <color name="ns_primaryDark">#577eac</color>
    <color name="ns_accent">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="ns_blue">#272734</color>
</resources>
```

Then I changed `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/SpinnerDatePicker</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>
</style>
```

> Note: I specified I want the spinner, but it's actually the default, I think.

I did a clean run

```
tns debug --hmr --clean
```

**The problem:** actually, the android `DatePicker` is still rendered using default colors, no my primary or accent colors as defined.

**Similar question:**

- [Nativescript Datepicker change text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298457/nativescript-datepicker-change-text-color) - Uses the same solution, so it's useless for me because this solution doesn't works (for me, actually)

Comment: I had a issue in my project where my folder structure was broken. What happened was that I had dupplicate files for my colors and resources in Android.
Somehow I had them in "App_Resources/Android" AND "App_Resources/Android/src/main/res".
Maybe you have this issue aswell?