# android Number picker text colour

Tags: android, textcolor, numberpicker

I want the values in number picker to be white.
I did the folloowing code which made it default black.

XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@layout/gradient_blue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Please select difficulty level"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/category_seperator"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <!--#019687-->
        <Button
            android:background="#019687"

            android:id="@+id/setting_confirm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="OK"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Javacode:

```
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_settings);

final NumberPicker n = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);

String easy = Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"white\">EASY</font>").toString();
String medium = Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"white\">MEDIUM</font>")+"";
String hard = Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"white\">HARD</font>")+"";
String tough = Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"white\">TOUGH</font>")+"";

//        String[] a = {"EASY", "MEDIUM", "HARD", "TOUGH"};
String [ ] a = {easy,medium,hard,tough};
n.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
n.setDisplayedValues(a);


n.setMaxValue(3);
n.setMinValue(0);
n.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

d.show();
```

I tried to change colour using html to as shown in code.
I also tried to change the colour using getChildAt and casting it to TextView which crashed the app.

[image: Number picker text colour]

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962075/change-the-text-color-of-numberpicker

Comment: Can you post your crash logs, because i use this exact same method and it works.

Comment: It didn't crashed actually got confused with some other answer
but neither worked for me
completes the try block shows log just before return statement yet the colour doesnot seem to change

used the method as 
_setNumberPickerTextColor(n,R.color.white);_

Comment: This is because you don't pass the resource color in this method. You pass the `Color` class's color. For Example, `Color.RED`

Comment: Thanks @eric247 that really worked out 
:D

Comment: Shall i post it as answer?

Comment: yes sure I shall tick your answer :) and plz upvote my quest :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94785/discussion-between-armas-cyndromic-and-eric247).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per our discussion in comments, the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962075/change-the-text-color-of-numberpicker), requires a parameter from the `Color` class. Pass a color using this class.

Answer (score 3):

Just use in your style.xml file **textColorPrimary** atribute:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

copied:
[Change the text color of NumberPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962075/change-the-text-color-of-numberpicker)

The color parameter should be from `Color` class e.g `Color.WHITE`

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public static boolean setNumberPickerTextColor(NumberPicker numberPicker, int color)
{
    final int count = numberPicker.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        View child = numberPicker.getChildAt(i);
        if(child instanceof EditText){
            try{
                Field selectorWheelPaintField = numberPicker.getClass()
                    .getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(true);
                ((Paint)selectorWheelPaintField.get(numberPicker)).setColor(color);
                ((EditText)child).setTextColor(color);
                numberPicker.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
            catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
                Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
            }
            catch(IllegalAccessException e){
                Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using Kotlin:

Just set the color of the number picker programatically:

```
numberPicker.textColor = 0xAARRGGBB.toInt()
```

example:

```
numberPicker.textColor = 0xAA3068D8.toInt()
```

Comment: only android q (API 29) and higher