# Android NumberPicker change text color

Tags: android, numberpicker

I'm new to Android and I'm implementing NumberPicker to one of my activities in my app. Below is the excerpt of my code:

```
picker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.order_confirm_bring_time_minute_picker);
picker.setMinValue(15);
picker.setMaxValue(120);
picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
setNumberPickerTextColor(picker, android.R.color.black);

public boolean setNumberPickerTextColor(NumberPicker numberPicker, int color)
{
    final int count = numberPicker.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        View child = numberPicker.getChildAt(i);
        if(child instanceof EditText){
            try{
                Field selectorWheelPaintField = numberPicker.getClass()
                        .getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(true);
                ((Paint)selectorWheelPaintField.get(numberPicker)).setColor(color);
                ((EditText)child).setTextColor(color);
                numberPicker.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
            catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
                Log.d("setNumberPickerTextColor", "NoSuchFieldException");
            }
            catch(IllegalAccessException e){
                Log.d("setNumberPickerTextColor", "IllegalAccessException");
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                Log.d("setNumberPickerTextColor", "IllegalArgumentException");
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've looked into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962075/change-the-text-color-of-numberpicker) for the `setNumberPickerTextColor` method. But it does not seem to work as I set my color to be changed to black, but it is not visible anymore. If I do not use the `setNumberPickerTextColor` method, then my default color is white, which can be seen when I highlight the text in the EditText field of the NumberPicker.

[image: color not changed]

This is a screenshot of the NumberPicker when the color is not changed.

[image: color changed to black]

This is a screenshot of the NumberPicker when the color is changed to black or any other color (I have tested and they give the same result).

Would there be a way to customize the text color in my NumberPicker? Also, I know it is a different question, but the colors of the top and bottom 'bar' as well because they do not fit the color theme of my app. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the resolved color to the setTextColor method, not the resource id.

```
((EditText)child).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(color));
```