# How can i change color of selected item in number picker and spinner

Tags: android

i want to change the colour of selected text in spinner. is there anyway i can change boundaries to white as well . same problem with number picker i want to appear color of numbers white either it is selected or not because all text in my project is white

```
 package myfyp.pkg.futureadvisor;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.NumberPicker;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class Enter_Info_Activity extends Activity {
           TextView t1,t2,t3;
           EditText e1,e2;
           Button b1;
           private Spinner spinner2;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.enterinfor);
            t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            t2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.programe);
            e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            t3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentage);
            addItemsOnSpinner2();
            NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np);
            np.setMinValue(0);
            //Specify the maximum value/number of NumberPicker
            np.setMaxValue(100);
            //Gets whether the selector wheel wraps when reaching the min/max value.
            np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

            //Set a value change listener for NumberPicker


            b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intenet=new Intent(v.getContext(),List_item.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intenet,0);  
                }
            });



        }
         public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

                spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Bachelor of Architecture");
                list.add("Bachelor of Business Administration");
                list.add("Bachelor of Commerce");
                list.add("Bachelor of Computer Information Systems");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Construction Technology");
                list.add("Bachelor of Criminal Justice");
                list.add("Bachelor of Economics");
                list.add("Bachelor of Education");
                list.add("Bachelor of Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Fine Arts");
                list.add("Bachelor of Information Systems");
                list.add("Bachelor of Social Work");
                list.add("Bachelor of Technology");
                list.add("Bachelor of Accountancy");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Aerospace Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Architecture");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Architectural Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Business Administration");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Business and Technology");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Chemical Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Chemistry");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Civil Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Computer Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Computer Science");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Criminal Justice");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Electrical Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Engineering Technology");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in English Literature");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Environmental Science");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in History");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Human Resources Management");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Industrial Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Information Technology");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Information Systems");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Information Systems");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Integrated Science");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Integrated Science");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in International Relations");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Journalism");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Manufacturing Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Marketing");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Mathematics");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Mechanical Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Mining Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Software Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Physics");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Politics");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Psychology");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Real-Time Interactive Simulation");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Religion");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Risk Management and Insurance");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Science Education");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Systems Engineering");
                list.add("Bachelor of Science in Veterinary Technology");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
              }



        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity1, menu);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.aboutusid) {
                Intent aboutusintent = new Intent(this,Aboutus_Activity.class); 
                startActivity(aboutusintent);
                return true;
            }
            else if (id == R.id.helpid) {
                Intent helpIntent = new Intent(this,Help_Activity.class); 
                startActivity(helpIntent);
                return true;
            }
            else if (id == R.id.homeid) {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class); 
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                return true;}
            else if (id == R.id.exitid) {

                finish();
                System.exit(0);

            }

            else if (id == R.id.exitid) {

                return false;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the layout for your `Adapter` with a [`ColorStateList`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html). You can create a `ColorStateList` using xml in your `color` resource folder like so:

```
<?xml version "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android/com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:color="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>
</selector>
```

Then you can create a layout using the `ColorStateList` (I use it here for the text color, but you can set any attribute that can use a color resource):

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp" android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/selector_accent"/>
```

Lastly, set this layout as your drop down view resource:

```
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.view_selectable);
```

---

As for the [`NumberPicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html), it doesn't look like there is a standard way to set the layout, but you should be able to change the color of the text, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22962195/5115932). Then just set the text color using your `ColorStateList`:

```
editText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.selector_accent));
```

Comment: for example you have 30 item in list view then 


   if(this)
    show 1,4,5,6,30 item
    elseif(this)
    show 10 28 17 45 item 
    .............
    if yes then how

Comment: @misbah That looks like an entirely separate question. The question stated above is just how to change the color of the text within a spinner and/or a number picker, which I believe I answered. What you are asking now seems like you want to apply a filter to your list view based on the spinner item clicked? Anyway, if you are asking a new question, post a new question. Link to it here in a new comment, and I will take a look at it.

Comment: sorry i am new to this site as well but this is the link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516587/how-to-use-selected-values-of-spinner-and-number-picker-for-if-else-statements