# How to change the TimePicker font color

Tags: android, android-timepicker

Working in an android app,Here I have a **TimePicker** with **spinner mode** and my layout background color is black.So I want to change the color of the **TimePicker's font to white** [Hour,Minute,AM/PM].

I have referred and tried so many solutions for this from SO ,But nothing is solved my problem.

Finally I found a source [Change the text color of NumberPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962075/change-the-text-color-of-numberpicker)

I have implemented as follows

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class CheckOut extends Activity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_alarm);

 mTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.mTimePicker);
int mycolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_background);
 setTimePickerColor(mTimePicker,mycolor);

}

 public static boolean setTimePickerColor(TimePicker timePicker, int color)
    {
        final int count = timePicker.getChildCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            View child = timePicker.getChildAt(i);
            if(child instanceof EditText){
                try{
                    Field selectorWheelPaintField = timePicker.getClass()
                            .getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                    selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(true);
                    ((Paint)selectorWheelPaintField.get(timePicker)).setColor(color);
                    ((EditText)child).setTextColor(color);
                    timePicker.invalidate();
                    return true;
                }
                catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
                    Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
                }
                catch(IllegalAccessException e){
                    Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
                }
                catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                    Log.w("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know where I did the mistake ,Because it is not make any effect .

Answer (score 0):

Problems and disadvantage to use android native `date and time picker`.

1. **Customisation is hard enough** that one will never want to spend hours on date picker.
2. **Date and Timer picker UI varies** in `pre lollipop` and `lollipop` device. (I mention this)

**Solution**

I always use [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) library to get rid of this problem. This library is highly customisable, well maintained repo.

I am sharing you my base activity class code, that you can add in your base activity class or make a new one.

You will extend your activity class by this base class. and just call simple method that i wrote.

```
openTimeDialog(Calendar.getInstance(), new OnTimeSelected() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(Calendar timeCalendar) {

            }
        });
```

**BaseProject.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by KHEMRAJ on 8/1/2017.
 */

public class BaseProject extends Activity {

    public interface OnDateSelected {
        void onDateSet(Calendar dateCalendar);
    }

    public interface OnTimeSelected {
        void onTimeSet(Calendar timeCalendar);
    }

    public void openDateDialog(OnDateSelected onDateSelected) {
        openDateDialog(Calendar.getInstance(), null, null, onDateSelected);
    }

    public void openDateDialog(@NonNull Calendar preSelectedCalendar, final OnDateSelected onDateSelected) {
        openDateDialog(preSelectedCalendar, null, null, onDateSelected);
    }

    public void openDateDialog(@NonNull Calendar preSelectedCalendar, @Nullable Calendar minDateCalander, final OnDateSelected onDateSelected) {
        openDateDialog(preSelectedCalendar, minDateCalander, null, onDateSelected);
    }

    public void openDateDialog(@NonNull Calendar preSelectedCalendar, @Nullable Calendar minDateCalander, @Nullable Calendar maxDateCalander, final OnDateSelected onDateSelected) {
        DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        if (onDateSelected != null) onDateSelected.onDateSet(calendar);
                    }
                },
                preSelectedCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                preSelectedCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                preSelectedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );
        if (minDateCalander != null)
            dpd.setMinDate(minDateCalander);
        if (maxDateCalander != null)
            dpd.setMaxDate(maxDateCalander);
        dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
    }

    public void openTimeDialog(@NonNull Calendar preSelectedCalendar, final OnTimeSelected onTimeSelected) {
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
                        if (onTimeSelected != null) onTimeSelected.onTimeSet(calendar);
                    }
                },
                preSelectedCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                preSelectedCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                false);
        timePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePickerDialog");
    }

}
```

Add this dependency

```
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.0'
```

You can change font colors, background colors, date time text colors as explained in [link](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)